# MVC run code/function on each row results LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I've very new to MVC (coming from Webforms) and i'm struggling to find how to do something that was simple with Webforms.

I have a list of data (properties) from the database using LINQ Query and this data is showing in the view and each row of this data has an unique id.

There are two things i'm trying to acheive, I need to run a funtion on each property and return a value, then display this in the view.
I also need to get more data (potentially more than 1 row) that is linked to that property (unique id) and then iterate through these in the view, so I guess I would have nested foreach statements to display the data under the property in the view, but I just have no idea where to run this query and how to display in the view.

With webforms I could quite easily write whatever I wanted in the ItemDataBound  event (if using a repeater), call a funtion in ItemDataBound or request more data and display in a nested repeater.

Controller - Gets list of properties

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    // list of pre-offer cases       
    IList<CurrentViewModel> CaseList = new List<CurrentViewModel>();
    var query = from cr in context.CaseRegs
                join c in context.PgsClients on cr.ClientID equals c.ClientID
                join s in context.PgsSites on cr.SiteID equals s.SiteID into scr from s in scr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join b in context.Buyins on cr.CaseID equals b.CaseID into bcr from b in bcr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where cr.arcStatus == "Current" && cr.withdrawn == null
                orderby cr.CaseID
                select new CurrentViewModel
                {
                    CaseID = cr.CaseID,
                    RegistrationDate = cr.RegistrationDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    ClientName = c.ClientName,
                    ClientCode = c.ClientCode,
                    SiteName = cr.SiteName,
                    SiteName2 = s.SiteName,
                    ClientPlot = cr.ClientPlot,
                    ContactName = cr.ContactName,
                    PxpStatus = cr.arcStatus,
                    CaseStatus = cr.caseStatus,
                    OwnerTitle = cr.ownerTitle,
                    OwnerFirstname = cr.ownerFirstname,
                    OwnerSurname = cr.ownerSurname,
                    PropertyAddress = cr.propertyAddress,
                    PropertyAddress2 = cr.propertyAddress2,
                    PropertyAddress3 = cr.propertyAddress3,
                    PropertyTown = cr.propertyTown,
                    PropertyCounty = cr.propertyCounty,
                    PropertyPostcode = cr.propertyPostcode,
                    TargetCompletionDate = b.TargetCompletionDate
                };

    CaseList = query.ToList();

    return View(CaseList);
}
```

Model

```
public class CurrentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string SiteName2 { get; set; }
    public string ClientPlot { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string PxpStatus { get; set; }
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
    public string OwnerTitle { get; set; }
    public string OwnerFirstname { get; set; }
    public string OwnerSurname { get; set; }
    public string PropertyAddress { get; set; }
    public string PropertyAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string PropertyAddress3 { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTown { get; set; }
    public string PropertyCounty { get; set; }
    public string PropertyPostcode { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? TargetCompletionDate { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<PGS.Models.ViewModels.CurrentViewModel>
@using PGS.Utilities

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Main_Template.cshtml";
}

<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7">
                <span class="record-count">@ViewBag.RecordCount</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Case</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>Target Completion</th>
            <th>Site/Plot</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Property</th>
            <th>Client</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            string RowClassName = "row-" + @item.CaseID;

            <tr class="row-click @RowClassName" data-url="/Case/Details/@item.CaseID/">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.RegistrationDate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.TargetCompletionDate.HasValue)
                    { @item.TargetCompletionDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Extensions.SitePlotFormat(item.ClientPlot, item.SiteName, item.SiteName2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Extensions.VendorNameFormat(item.OwnerTitle, item.OwnerFirstname, item.OwnerSurname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Extensions.PropertyShortAddressFormat(item.PropertyAddress, item.PropertyTown, item.PropertyCounty, item.PropertyPostcode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientCode)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Model for viewings for each property

```
public class ViewingViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Applicant { get; set; }
    public int AgentID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and relevant code you tried please

Comment: Added code as it currently is thanks.

Comment: You do not need to post the entire code. Just post only relevant code(for the question you are asking) . What method you want to run on each properties and what value you are expecting  ? What is stopping you from running that methods ?

Comment: As it says in the question, I'm learning MVC and don't know how to go about it, so just asking for some direction. I have a list working and showing data in the view, but not sure how I go about getting the second model to display for each row of the CurrentViewModel.

Comment: I think you've been downvoted because the question seems impregnable with all that code!  Possibly breaking it down into smaller problems might have been better.  Anyway, regarding the first question - what does this function do?, and for the 2nd question it sounds like to need to add a List<> property to `CurrentViewModel` and populate this with a subquery

Comment: @markpsmith. Thanks. I've added: `public List<ViewingViewModel> ViewingViewModels { get; set; }` to the model. When I add `@foreach (var viewing in Model.ViewingViewModels)` in the view I get an error in code "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PGS.Models.ViewModels.CurrentViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'ViewingViewModels' and no extension method 'ViewingViewModels' accepting a first argument of type"

Comment: @JBoom that's because your model is `IEnumerable<CurrentViewModel>` and `ViewingViewModels` property is in the `CurrentViewModel` class. See my answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in your view

```
@model IEnumerable<PGS.Models.ViewModels.CurrentViewModel>
```

and a `foreach` loop inside `<tbody>` like below

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            ...
            ...
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I'd say that's a good start for displaying the list of `CurrentViewModel` in a table. If I understand your question correctly, it looks like an instance of `CurrentViewModel` can have multiple instances of `ViewingViewModel` and you want something like below as the end result:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            .... 
            .... display the instances of ViewingViewModel here
            ....
        </td>
        ....
        ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            .... 
            .... display the instances of ViewingViewModel here
            ....
        </td>
        ....
        ....
    </tr>
    ....
    ....
</tbody>
```

The first thing you need to do is adding a new property with `List<ViewingViewModel>` as the type to `CurrentViewModel`

```
public class CurrentViewModel
{
    ....
    .... your other properties
    ....

    public List<ViewingViewModel> ViewingViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Keep in mind that there's no `ItemDataBound` event in ASP.NET MVC like in WebForms, so the sub query to get the related ViewingViewModels must be done in the controller after the main query and before `return View(CaseList);`. Below is the changed controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<CurrentViewModel> CaseList = new List<CurrentViewModel>();
    var query = .... // your existing query as in the question

    CaseList = query.ToList();

    foreach (var cvm in CaseList)
    {
        cvm.ViewingViewModels = .... // do the query to get the ViewingViewModels here
    }

    return View(CaseList);        
}
```

and finally add the nested `foreach` in your view

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @foreach (var detail in item.ViewingViewModels)
                {
                    .... display ViewingViewModels here
                }
            </td>
            ...
            ...
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment and assuming all the properties of `ViewingViewModel` correspond to properties of `SaleViewings` with the same names, the controller code should be like below

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<CurrentViewModel> CaseList = new List<CurrentViewModel>();
    var query = .... // your existing query as in the question

    CaseList = query.ToList();

    foreach (var cvm in CaseList)
    {
        cvm.ViewingViewModels = (from sv in context.SaleViewings 
                                where sv.CaseID == cvm.CaseID 
                                select new ViewingViewModel
                                {
                                    ID = sv.ID,
                                    CaseID = sv.CaseID,
                                    Date = sv.Date,
                                    Applicant = sv.Applicant,
                                    AgentID = sv.AgentID
                                }).ToList();
    }

    return View(CaseList);        
}
```

Remember that the type of `cvm.ViewingViewModels` is `List<ViewingViewModel>`, so when you do something like

```
cvm.ViewingViewModels = ....
```

always make sure that the right side also returns an instance of `List<ViewingViewModel>`.

Comment: Thanks ekad. I have an error on the query now. I've added `foreach (var cvm in CaseList) { cvm.ViewingViewModels = from sv in context.SaleViewings where sv.CaseID == cvm.CaseID select sv; }` but get an error on the WHERE: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PGS.Models.SaleViewing>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PGS.Models.ViewModels.ViewingViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)'

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You have to make sure that your query at the right side returns an instance of `List<PGS.Models.ViewModels.ViewingViewModel>` instead of `System.Linq.IQueryable<PGS.Models.SaleViewing>`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense now and is working. Thanks for your help & patience.